# How to replace JSON values double quotes with single quotes with Regex

Tags: arrays, json, regex, string

I use an old legacy framework that connects to a non-relational DB that can only receive a JSON string like this:

```
'{
"id":'123',
"name":'myZoo',
"ticketPrice":66.5,
"animals":['lion','zebra','wolf']
}'
```

I have this JSON string:

```
'{
"id":"123",
"name":"myZoo",
"ticketPrice":66.5,
"animals":["lion","zebra","wolf"]
}'
```

Using regex, I want to replace double quotes `"` with single quotes `'` of the JSON values only ( the keys must have double quotes ).

the reason I want to use regex is because my framework cant handle JSON so I need to use it as string.

For a JSON without arrays I have this code:

```
/(?<=:)"((?:\\.|[^\\])*?)"/g
```

But, I cant make it work with arrays.

Answer (score 1):

So I think what you mean by saying it doesn't work with arrays is the case of the `"animals"` key.  Could you just check if the JSON value is an array then use apply your regex to each individual element in the array then build a new array with your new elements?